# Changing Participant Status - generates wrong email

Tags: civievent

At this point in our application process, 'Awaiting approval' is our desired, and standard participant status. However, if a record needs altered and the status is changed away from that for the alteration, and then back to 'awaiting approval' the auto generated acknowledgement mail defaults with 'You have been added to the WAIT LIST for this event.' which isn't the case and causes concern. Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: This sounds like a bug in CiviCRM. You could uncheck the sending of e-mails as soon as you update the participant status. Not sure whether that helps you.

Comment: Use a different status or an action for your administrative process. Awaiting approval does put them back on the wait list. Or change the email text.